# What will happen to the allocated memory on GPU, after the application using it exits, if cudaFree() was not used?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

If cudaFree() is not used in the end, will the memory being used automatically get free, after the application/kernel function using it exits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

When your application terminates (be it gracefully or not), all of its memory is reclaimed back by the OS, regardless of whether it had `free`d it or not.
Similarly, the memory allocated on the GPU is managed by its driver, which will release all the resources your application held, `cudaFree`d or not.

It is however good practice that every allocation has a matching deallocation, so don't use that as an excuse to not deallocate your memory properly :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Gregor :) But if release of resources is automatically done by GPU drivers after application ends, why increase the work-load of the programmer(one more thing to remember and do) and length of code(which means harder to write and debug) by suggesting de-allocation as a good practice?

Comment: Hi @Buzz, that's a good question and the answer isn't trivial, so you may as well ask it as a separate question. Simply put, in general every allocation should have a matching deallocation. Skipping deallocation in a long-running process would result in a memory leak followed by a crash as the system runs out of memory. Skipping deallocation in a short-lived process or during application shutdown can be considered an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if you do not free memory in a loop, or if you claim memory multiple times, the claimed memory will accumulate. Eventually the system will run out of memory.